# In C# When is the right time to use Apostrophe Quotation marks

Tags: c#, .net, syntax

I would like to know why some things have to be within a pair of Apostrophes and others within Quotation marks?

```
void trythis(){

char myChar = 'Stuff';
String myString = "Blah";
int myInteger = '22'; 
Serial.print(myChar );
Serial.print(myString );
Serial.print(myInteger );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Number should have no quotes `int x= 56`
- characters have single quotes `char ch = 'a';`
- strings have double quotes `string name = "Bob";`

Answer (score 1):

*Character* literals use a single quote. So when you're dealing with `char`, that's `'x'`.

*String* literals use double quotes. So when you're dealing with `string`, that's `"x"`.

A `char` is a single UTF-16 code unit - in most cases "a single character". A string is a *sequence* of UTF-16 code units, i.e. "a piece of text" of (nearly) arbitrary length.

Your final example, after making it compile, would look something like:

```
int myInteger = 'x';
```

That's using a character literal, but then implicitly converting it to `int` - equivalent to:

```
char tmp = 'x';
int myInteger = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote doesn't compile at all.

Single quotes are used for character literals (single characters, which are stored as UTF-16 in .NET). Integers are not quoted.

This would be valid:

```
char myChar = 's';
string myString = "Blah";
int myInteger = 22;
```

Comment: It compiles just fine, but its for an Arduino so maybe that's why.